# Apertar botões do teclado virtual de acordo com a senha

Tags: php, json, array

Fiz um teclado virtual que gera os números e retorna em json, por exemplo:

```
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 1
                    [b] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 6
                    [b] => 7
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 4
                    [b] => 9
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 8
                    [b] => 2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 3
                    [b] => 0
                )
```

O código acima gera os números no seguinte formato: A ou B
Por exemplo: Pressione este botão caso sua senha for entre A ou B.

E junto com esse código, tem uma variável que define a senha da pessoa, no caso, a senha é 011232. Os valores que o teclado virtual dá são aleatórios.

Preciso de um código que pegue os valores entre os 5 botões e verifique botão por botão, se a senha da variável é igual um dos dois valores (A e B)

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Note que o código citado na pergunta _não_ é JSON, mas um literal de _array_ do PHP. Ademais, sua pergunta não está clara. Você quer a sequência de índices do _array_ principal do teclado que corresponde ao que um usuário apertaria ao usar o teclado para digitar a senha?

Answer (score 0):

Montei em JS

```js
var teclas = [{"a":1,"b":5},{"a":6,"b":7},{"a":4,"b":9},{"a":8,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":0}];
var password = '011232';
var check = 0;

function checkPassword(e){
    var index = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
    var arr = [parseInt(teclas[index].a), parseInt(teclas[index].b)];
    if(arr.indexOf(parseInt(password[check])) != -1){
        check++;
    }else{
        check = 0;
        alert('Password Error');
    }

    if(check >= password.length){
        alert('Password OK');
    check = 0;
    }
}

function createButton(i){

    var o = teclas[i];

    var button = document.createElement('input');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.value = o.a+','+o.b;
    button.setAttribute('data-index', i);
    button.addEventListener('click', checkPassword);

    return button;
}

var teclado = document.getElementById('teclado');
for(var i=0; i < teclas.length; i++){
    teclado.appendChild(createButton(i));
}
```

```html
<div id="teclado">
</div>
```

Comment: Preciso em PHP =/

Answer (score -1):

A solução para seu problema.
Passe o link na variável $url, e não esqueça de passar a senha pelo método GET.

```
<?php


echo $senha = $_GET['senha'];


$p1 = $senha[0];
$p2 = $senha[1];
$p3 = $senha[2];
$p4 = $senha[3];
$p5 = $senha[4];
$p6 = $senha[5];


echo "<br>------ R A N D O M  ----------<br>";
$url = "cole sua url aqui";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$json = curl_exec($ch);

$obj = json_decode($json);

$obj->a[0];
$obj->a[1];
$obj->b[0];
$obj->b[1];
$obj->c[0];
$obj->c[1];
$obj->d[0];
$obj->d[1];
$obj->e[0];
$obj->e[1];

switch($p1){
   case $obj->a[0]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->a[1]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->b[0]:
         echo "b";
         break;
   case $obj->b[1]:
         echo "b";
         break;
    case $obj->c[0]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->c[1]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->d[0]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->d[1]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->e[0]:
         echo "e";
         break;
    case $obj->e[1]:
         echo "e";
         break;
   default:
         echo "Jogue novamente";
         break;
}

switch($p2){
   case $obj->a[0]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->a[1]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->b[0]:
         echo "b";
         break;
   case $obj->b[1]:
         echo "b";
         break;
    case $obj->c[0]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->c[1]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->d[0]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->d[1]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->e[0]:
         echo "e";
         break;
    case $obj->e[1]:
         echo "e";
         break;
   default:
         echo "Jogue novamente";
         break;
}

switch($p3){
   case $obj->a[0]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->a[1]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->b[0]:
         echo "b";
         break;
   case $obj->b[1]:
         echo "b";
         break;
    case $obj->c[0]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->c[1]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->d[0]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->d[1]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->e[0]:
         echo "e";
         break;
    case $obj->e[1]:
         echo "e";
         break;
   default:
         echo "Jogue novamente";
         break;
}
switch($p4){
   case $obj->a[0]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->a[1]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->b[0]:
         echo "b";
         break;
   case $obj->b[1]:
         echo "b";
         break;
    case $obj->c[0]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->c[1]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->d[0]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->d[1]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->e[0]:
         echo "e";
         break;
    case $obj->e[1]:
         echo "e";
         break;
   default:
         echo "Jogue novamente";
         break;
}
switch($p5){
   case $obj->a[0]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->a[1]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->b[0]:
         echo "b";
         break;
   case $obj->b[1]:
         echo "b";
         break;
    case $obj->c[0]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->c[1]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->d[0]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->d[1]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->e[0]:
         echo "e";
         break;
    case $obj->e[1]:
         echo "e";
         break;
   default:
         echo "Jogue novamente";
         break;
}
switch($p6){
   case $obj->a[0]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->a[1]:
         echo "a";
         break;
   case $obj->b[0]:
         echo "b";
         break;
   case $obj->b[1]:
         echo "b";
         break;
    case $obj->c[0]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->c[1]:
         echo "c";
         break;
    case $obj->d[0]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->d[1]:
         echo "d";
         break;
    case $obj->e[0]:
         echo "e";
         break;
    case $obj->e[1]:
         echo "e";
         break;
   default:
         echo "Jogue novamente";
         break;
}
```